# How to use a lib file in a console c++ app

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm new to c++ (I'm used to c#) so this question is very basic (have been searching the web for an answer with no success).

I have a console C++ app and in it, I want to invoke a function that is located in a different project.

I have created and compiled a dll type project and then referenced it from my console app(by clicking the right mouse button on the console project and clicking add reference in vs) with no errors.

I'm trying to add a reference to that file like this:

```
#include "SharedDLL.h"
```

But I get an error saying the file cannot be found.

how should this be done?

tnx in advance...

Comment: Edit your question, provide us with your code sample, your compilation line, screenshot, error details.

Comment: Being used to C# does not help you, C# has very strong support for modules but that is missing in C++.  Adding a reference is only good enough to tell the linker to link the .lib file.  But not good enough to tell the compiler where to look for the .h file.  Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories setting.

Comment: @ Passant When i compile my dll project the output is a .dll file, but no header file (only pch) - should i reference the pch file?

Comment: @Passant following your comment i managed to include the dll and use it, Tnx

Answer (score 1):

A Dynamically-Linked Library DLL comes with two major files, a `.h` file to include, and a `.lib` file to link

First you include it in your code like this

```
#include "SharedDLL.h"
```

Then you compiler with the following option

```
/EHsc /link SharedDLL.lib
```

On visual studio, you need to do the following :

> 7. On the Application Settings page, under Additional options, clear the Precompiled header check box.

- And make sure you referenced your DLL, by following [these steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47w1hdab.aspx)

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)

Comment: where can i specify the location of the file? or should i copy it to dierctory from which i run my exe?

Comment: @barakcaf when you include the DLL like `#include "SharedDLL.h"` this mean it's in the same directory, then it should be along with it. If you are using VS, then you can add the path to the DLL directory in the project settings.

Comment: @barakcaf not `dierctory from which i run my exe` but the directory from which you compile it.

Comment: I still get an error saying the file cannot be found (i've copied the dll into the console app directory)...

Comment: @barakcaf You should copy that header file in the project you're using the DLL in, too.

Comment: @barakcaf has this already solved your problem, if so please mark it as the correct answer for future readers.